# NRLMSISE atmospheric drag model in GMAT

Tags: gmat

I'm using GMAT (R2018a) software for orbital propagation and now testing the atmospheric drag.

There are only 2 options: JacciaRoberts and MSISE90. Is there a way to add NRLMSISE00 to the options?

I have already checked the documentation: it's said that NRLMSISE00 is added by plugin, however, didn't find anything. It's said, this model is for internal use only..

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this issue in R2020a few days ago. When comparing the results for the same orbit and simulation parameters in GMAT (MSISE00/JacchiaRoberts) and Orekit (NRLMSISE00), there is a difference of almost 100 km along track after 10 days for a LEO small satellite. I know this a atmosphere issue because without atmospheric model, the results from GMAT and Orekit match.

As NRLMSISE00 is the newer model, I would prefer Orekit if atmospheric modelling is critical for your work. I hope the GMAT Team addresses this issue.